# Making a port scanning tool for fun to help brush up on GUI, Threads and Networking, need some advice

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking

Okay so while I have a ton on my plate as is, I still want to create something of interest to help exercise my CS knowledge.

Okay, so I have the barebones down. I started with a basic, single threaded application, basically just a for loop that goes through each port by testing a socket connection and if it throws an IO exception, there isn't anything, but If it doesn't it outputs there is something listening on that port. That worked fine although very, VERY slowly.

Then I went on to make a subclass of thread that individually checked the ports assigned to it. That also worked well, as I allocated 100 threads to evenly (as possible) try each port. Even had a bootstrap for the initialization of the thread by having a method handle it.
However I have two things I need addressing. One, how will I know when I have just too many threads? Obviously assigning 65,535 threads for each port is a bad idea and 1 thread for each port is also bad too. I'm assuming that anything more than 100 threads is pushing it with overhead costs. Would 1,000 be too much then if each thread basically gets 65 each on average. I'd assume so, but 100 threads where each thread has to handle 655 each is also quite a bit but a significant improvement.
Second, how do I get the hostname of the connection using that port. Each time I just get localhost or 127.0.0.1 but I want the ip and if possible the hostname of the connection.
I'd like to say that the code this is based on is what my professor presented in class that I wanted to build upon. I don't care for managing the thread so I won't need a thread pool as I don't plan on reusing them.

Oh yeah I've got another question. When do I want to implement runnable and when do I want to extend thread. I like using anonymous methods, I.E Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {...} ); and since Runnable is an interface then it can't be instantiated right? So is it possible to say so Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {...}; like in the thread parameter?

Code here => http://pastebin.com/6UKRZdDE

Also I know I should use Executor instead of Threads, but as of now I kind of wrote it in like 10 - 15 minutes and couldn't figure out how to get the hostname or IP Address of the connection using the port.

To emphasize my question:

1) Is there some kind of math to find the optimal amount of threads to use in an application?

2) How do I find the hostname and/or IP Address of the connection that's using a port in java?

Thanks.

Comment: *looks at question - head explodes.* Please reformat your question into manageable paragraphs. I cannot read this :(

Comment: Quickly reformatted as per your request.

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

To find the optimal amount of threads scanning the ports, you might want to start with setting a timelimit for the searching. That is, how much time should the searching take at most?

If you are doing this on your own machine only (as I understood it), you could try finding the maximum amount of concurrent threads your machine can handle:

```
public class Test {

    private static Object o = new Object();
    private static int threads = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                synchronized(o) {
                    threads += 1;
                    System.err.println("Thread number " + threads);
                }

                while(true) {
                    try { Thread.sleep(1000); }
                    catch (Exception e) { System.err.println(e); }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

}
```

My machine (~8gb RAM) can handle about 100,000 threads before throwing an exception.

With this, I would have no issues scanning ports with 10,000 threads; each thread having to scan 6 ports. I think we can do with less threads anyway... Find out how much time scanning each port takes, and use an appropriate amount of threads to scan through them all.

Note that scanning all 65,535 ports is the absolute worst-case scenario.

**2.**

I'm not sure I understood this question correctly, but you can get a socket's IP address with `socket.getInetAddress();`

Comment: 1. I have to say, that code looks beautiful, with that lambda notation. I always wanted to learn how to utilize it more often. The second beauty of it is that it actually caused my computer to blue screen at around 67,537 or something, so while I can make 60k threads at once, I don't want to cause another blue screen. I'm surprised though, why was it that it threw an exception for you? I just got a BSOD.


2. When I use socket.getInetAddress() I get 127.0.0.1

Comment: At least I can say I got my answer. 10,000 seems to be enough to drastically speed things up, but each thread isn't really getting that much of a quantum slice, so it's really all over the place with what thread does what. It's faster, for sure, but what I thought would be just 6 - 7 instructions per thread is taking quite a bit of time, but it's finding a lot of open ports.

Comment: @KyleStanly It could be that this is an old version of the code I wrote for the heck of it a while ago. The updated version threw the exception correctly. I'm sorry if this code BSOD'd you :') I'll try to fix it asap

Comment: I'm kinda scared to use it hah. I've a question though, why is it that Java doesn't prevent the old code from causing a crash, or why doesn't the OS prevent it from happening? Couldn't ANY program just spam a bunch of threads to bring everything down to force a BSOD?

Comment: @KyleStanly I tested it myself, and after a while my JVM crashed.  It seems it's your problem :/